# Grab specific value from string with PHP

Tags: php

I want to grab the full contents of the value `utm_campaign` from the ***$page*** variable using the following PHP:

```
$page = "utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Test | Test - Exact&utm_test=test";
preg_match_all('#utm_campaign=([^\s&]+)#', $page, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

However the above *var_dump* only outputs the following:

`Test`

Comment: Well, your regex contains `\s` which means it's stopping as soon as it finds a space. So if you remove `\s` your regex would work. However, it's very strange for an URL to contain spaces, they should be encoded as %20, so I think you should revisit how you obtained `$page` in the first place

Comment: I've run this on three different versions of PHP and the result is identical each time: `array(2) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(15) "utm_campaign=Te" } [1]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(2) "Te" } }`.  Are you _certain_ that it is outputting just `Test` and not more?

Comment: Maybe parse_str is what you're looking for: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `parse_str` instead:

```
$page = "utm_source=google&utm_campaign=Test | Test - Exact&utm_test=test";
$res = [];
parse_str($page, $res);
var_dump($res);
```

This gives you:

```
array(3) { ["utm_source"]=> string(6) "google" ["utm_campaign"]=> string(19) "Test | Test - Exact" ["utm_test"]=> string(4) "test" }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is excluding spaces and &, this is what `^` does int `[^\s&]` so the match stops after the space in test.  If you want the whole thing, change your regex to `#utm_campaign=([^&]+)#`

Using an online regex tester you can see what is being matched and not.

https://regex101.com/r/Frxwg0/1/